# How do you configure MinGW with Sublime Text 3?

Tags: c, windows, sublimetext3

I recently installed MinGW  and I've been trying to get it to work with Sublime Text 3 to get it to open cmd when when I compile the script, however nothing works.

When I go to **Tools > Build System > New Build System** and save this script, I keep on getting an error:

> '"C:...." is not recognized as an internal or external command
>   operable program or batch file.'

For some reason, the executable is never created. How do you get this to work? I have gcc in C:\MinGW\bin

```
{
"cmd": ["gcc", "${file}", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe"],
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.c, source.c++",
"shell": true,

"variants":
[
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe"],
        "shell": true
    }
]
}
```

Comment: you need to add C:\MinGW\bin to the PATH variable ;-)

Comment: I did add it and it does not work.

Comment: It does work for me as the only thing I did was adding C:\MinGW\bin to the PATH...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works as I had intended:

```
{
"cmd": ["gcc", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&", "start", "cmd", "/k" , "$file_base_name"],
"selector": "source.c",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"shell": true
}
```